# Question about combo box and labels

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combo box that contains 5 items. I have one label on the window. What i would like to do is whenever a user clicks on one of the items in the combobox, text will populate that label. I would like to show information about whichever item is selected (IP address, etc.). Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Code:

```
private void cmbGroups_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    //Combo box selection changed. Re-bind data 
    string selectedGroup = (string)cmbGroups.SelectedItem; 
    BindGrid(selectedGroup); 
}
```

Code:

```
    private void BindGrid(string selectedGroup)
    {
        //Re-bind the grid
        dgPortStatus.DataContext = _dicPortStatus[selectedGroup].Portstatus.DefaultView;

        InitializeColumns();
    }
```

Code:

```
private void _UpdatePortStatus()
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["portStatusDir"], "PortStatus.*");

        foreach (string file in files)
        {

            PortStatus ps = new PortStatus();
            ps.ReadXml(new StreamReader(file));
            //ps.ReadXml(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

            if (!_dicPortStatus.ContainsKey(ps.General[0].Group))
            {
                _dicPortStatus.Add(ps.General[0].Group, ps);
            }

            PortStatus psOrig = _dicPortStatus[ps.General[0].Group];

            foreach (PortStatus.PortstatusRow psr in ps.Portstatus.Rows)
            {
                DataRow[] drs = psOrig.Portstatus.Select("PortNumber = '" + psr.PortNumber + "'");

                if (drs.Length == 1)
                {
                    DateTime curDt = DateTime.Parse(drs[0]["LastUpdateDateTimeUTC"].ToString());
                    DateTime newDt = psr.LastUpdateDateTimeUTC;

                    if (newDt > curDt)
                    {
                        drs[0]["LastUpdateDateTimeUTC"] = newDt;
                    }
                }
                else if (drs.Length == 0)
                {
                    psOrig.Portstatus.ImportRow(psr);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("More than one of the same portnumber on PortStatus file: " + file);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (string groupName in _dicPortStatus.Keys)
        {
            if (!cmbGroups.Items.Contains(groupName))
            {
                cmbGroups.Items.Add(groupName);
                cmbGroups.SelectedItem = groupName;
            }
        }
```

Code:

```
private Dictionary<string, PortStatus> _dicPortStatus = new Dictionary<string, PortStatus>()
```

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF???

Comment: I am working on a WPF project

Comment: I have added a wpf tag to your question.  Adding the right tags to your questions will help people answer more accurately and attract people who are interested in those tags. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox1">
...
<ComboBox />

<Label Text="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox1, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

--EDIT--

**Extended Example**:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Name="ComboBox1"
                  DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"></ComboBox>
        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox1, Path=SelectedValue}">
            <Label Content="{Binding FirstName}" />
            <Label Content="{Binding LastName}" />
            <Label Content="{Binding Age}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>() { 
            new Person(){ FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Age = 25 },
            new Person(){ FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith", Age = 35 },
            new Person(){ FirstName = "Susan", LastName = "Smith", Age = 31 },
            new Person(){ FirstName = "Anthony", LastName = "Jones", Age = 31 },
        };

        ComboBox1.ItemsSource = persons;
```

Class:

```
public class Person
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public Int32 Age { get; set; }
}
```

--EDIT:2--

Create a new class:

```
class GroupInfo
{
    public String GroupName { get; set; }
    public String IP { get; set; }
}
```

And change your code to following:

```
    foreach (string groupName in _dicPortStatus.Keys)
    {
        if (!cmbGroups.Items.Contains(groupName))
        {
            cmbGroups.Items.Add(new GroupInfo(){ GroupName = groupName, IP = <Write Code to get IP>);
            cmbGroups.SelectedItem = groupName;
        }
    }
```

Change XAML to following:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" DisplayMemberPath="GroupName">
    ...
<ComboBox />

<Label Text="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox1, Path=SelectedItem.IP}" />
```

Comment: How would I define what each selected item should display?

Comment: You can use `Path=SelectedItem.PropertyName`

Comment: Will this work to fill a label on the form with info on whatever item i select in the combobox?

Comment: So here is what Im trying to do...I have a combobox that has 5 items. Each item is pulling data from a different server. What i want to do is, when an item is selected, i want to show the IP address for that server in a separate label.

Comment: Do you use `ItemsSource` on your `ComboBox` or statically added items? You will need to post some more code.

Comment: No static items. All items are pulled in from an xml file

Comment: As I said, post more code on how you populate that `ComboBox`.

Comment: private void cmbGroups_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Combo box selection changed.  Re-bind data
            string selectedGroup = (string)cmbGroups.SelectedItem;

            BindGrid(selectedGroup);
}

Comment: You can edit your own question and add code there. I did it this time. And I want to know if you are using a collection of class like I did here (using collection of `Person` class) to populate ComboBox?

Comment: This code is not relevant. I was looking for the code that binds `ComboBox`. But, let me be more specific. What is the type of object that you get using `ComboBox`'s `SelectedItem` property? Because that's what we want to bind to `Label`.

Comment: Ok i added some more. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Ok, I see now. You have a list of strings added to your `ComboBox`. Now, what you want to do is when any item is selected in `ComboBox`, you want to display related IP to that group, right?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the IP's that I need to display need to be hard coded since they will not change.

Comment: I am confused by the write the code to get the IP part...would that just be what i reference in the groupinfo class? do i just need to make a list of the IP's?

Comment: You need a list of class that has both `group name` and `related ip` in it. Not two separate lists, but one list. How would you go and hard-code the IPs? Are IPs dependent on group name? Use that logic.

Answer (score 2):

in Win Forms:

```
comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += onSelectedIndexChanged;

private void onSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  object item = comboBox.SelectedItem;
  string text = //get text from item
  label.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: Each selected item will display different text. Is there a way to do this and have each item display something different?

Comment: @Joe: instead of `//get text from item` you need to call some function to get a specific text for the `item`.  But it still won't help you since you are interested in Wpf.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can try something like this

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e)
{

    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;

    string myItemText = (string) ComboBox1.SelectedItem;

    // populate
    MyTextBox.Text = myItemText;

}
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as the accepted answer, by clicking the tick to the left of the question. :)

Comment: So if I did it this way, How would I define what each item would list in the label?